# What does "QE-DEF-0469 QE Message" mean?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi, cognos-tm1

I'm working on Cognos 10.1.

For a report, I've updated the package. When I open the report in report studio, it is showing an error like **QE-DEF-0469 QE Message**. What does it mean? Earlier responses would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error below appears when trying to run a report in Report Studio.

QE-DEF-0469 QE MessageRQP-DEF-0542 Metadata will be retrieved from the database, because metadata governor is turned off (Change FM governor: Enhanced model portability).

Resolving the problem

Uncheck the "Allow enhanced model portability at runtime" option in Framework Manager

Steps:
Open the model in Framework Manager

Click on the Edit Governors option in the Tasks section, alternatively go to Project Menu\edit Governors

Uncheck the "Allow enhanced model portability at runtime" check box

Source: ibm.com